# Correct way to load a partial view into a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am wanting to create a view that allows me to add phone numbers for a person.

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneModel
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDetailViewModel
{
    public PersonModel PersonDetails { get; set; }
    public IList<PhoneModel> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

I am binding my main view to the viewmodel like

```
@model DynamicPhoneNumber.Models.PersonDetailViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Add";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Details</legend>Name @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.PersonDetails.Name)
    <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Press Me" />
    <div id="mydiv">
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

My Partial view looks like

```
@model DynamicPhoneNumber.Models.PhoneModel
<p>
@Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.PhoneNumber)
</p>
```

Im using jquery to dynamically add the partial view.

On HttpPost I place a breakpoint and I can see the value from the PersonDetails.Name however none of the values from my loaded partialview are been bound to the PhoneModel.

What do I need to do to be able to return the data from the partial views into my viewmodel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a good blog post that may help to resolve your problem

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx